# Guardar fecha y hora desde DropdownList

Tags: c#, sql

Buenas tardes tengo esta tabla donde quiero guardar la fecha junto con la hora.

El campo "FechaInicio" es un DateTime.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que el usuario seleccione los datos de los siguientes dropdownlist, quisiera que me ayudaran a saber como puedo seleccionar dia, mes, año, hora y minutos por separado, pero luego unirlo en una sola fecha con hora en una variable , e insertarla en la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías usar el constructor de un nuevo `[DateTime][1]` pasandole como parametros el año, mes, dia, hora, minutos y segundos tal que así:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(anio, mes, dia, hora, minutos, segundos);
```

Puedes ver la prueba que he hecho [aquí](https://rextester.com/OKB42389)

A la hora de ponerlo a la base de datos debes construir la query y pasarle como parámetro la fecha:

```
string SQLcm = " INSERT INTO tabla (fecha) VALUES (@fecha) ";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLcm);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", dt);
```

Comment: Funciono correctamente, muchas gracias.

Comment: @aledaysp Recuerda marcar la respuesta con el check verde para indicar a llos demás usuarios que te ha servido la respuesta.